# How to convert an Object to an array in PHP7?

Tags: php

When I use get_object_vars() php function, public variables are all fine to convert to array but the problem is private and protected variables.

Is there any way or good way to convert it?

Comment: Please provide code to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what is your expected result?